# python numpy - Function to perform vector & matrix addition

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on the problem which asks me:

Add two NumPy vectors or matrices together, if possible. If it is not possible to add the two vectors/matrices together (because their sizes differ), return False.

Here is my approach:

```
import numpy as np

def mat_addition(A, B):
    if A.shape != B.shape:
        return False
    else:
        return np.sum(A,B)
```

But when I run the code for testing, it says

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: From the docs on `np.sum()`: "Sum of array elements over a given axis". The np.sum function is meant for adding the values in a single array. If you want to add two arrays, you can call `A+B`. The "scalar index" being referred to is the axis over which to sum the values.

Comment: Thank you Anderson!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.sum` can in fact be used in the way you want. You just need to wrap the arguments you pass to `np.sum` in a list:

```
import numpy as np

def mat_addition(A, B):
    if A.shape != B.shape:
        return False
    else:
        return np.sum([A,B])

a = np.arange(5*3).reshape(5,3)
b = np.arange(5*3, 5*3*2).reshape(5,3)
print(mat_addition(a,b))
```

Output:

```
435
```

As per the [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) docs, this function expects a single "array_like" object as its first argument. A list of arrays is a perfectly valid "array_like" object, so the above code works.